# Indent multiline text in console

Tags: c#, console

Is there clean way to indent multiline text in the console?

For example, when you write the code bellow, only first line appears indented.

```
Console.WriteLine($"  {ex.Message}");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in way to do this, but one way is to use `Regex.Replace` to add indentation at the beginning on each line. With `RegexOptions.Multiline` a `^` matches the beginning of each line:

```cs
// ex.Message = "This is a sting with\nmultiple lines of text\r\nwith different line endings";
var indented = Regex.Replace(ex.Message, "^", "  ", RegexOptions.Multiline);
Console.WriteLine(indented);
```

```
  This is a sting with
  multiple lines of text
  with different line endings
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/ArfVeH

Comment: I think this doesn't solve the problem since most exception messages doesn't have \r or \n characters. The text appears on multiple lines just becouse it doesn't fit on one line.

Comment: @JaimeOro Ah, the OP just says "multiline", but if you meant when a single line wraps onto the next line, then I don't think you can do that unless you're using a different console with that specific feature.

Comment: @JaimeOro Instead you should consider using a logging framework where you can customize the output much better. E.g. Log4Net, NLog, Serilog...